# Не работают стандартные библиотеки в CUDA проекте

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda

Среда Visual Studio 2017.
Изучаю CUDA программирование, делаю по этому уроку https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSDBfaXWwnw, в конце программы ставлю getchar(); среда ругается, что идентификатор не определен.
Если пробую как здесь https://habrahabr.ru/post/54330/ делать, то аналогичная ошибка здесь #include  и прочие стандартные библиотеки не видно.
Подскажите уроки/статьи, по которым можно изучать CUDA или что я здесь делаю не так?
вот код

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    
__global__ void addArrays(int* a, int* b, int* c)
{
int idx = threadIdx.x;
c[idx] = a[idx] + b[idx];
}

int main()
{
int ha[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
int hb[] = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5 };
int hc[5];

int *da, *db, *dc;

int size = sizeof(int) * 5;

cudaMalloc((void**)&da, size);
cudaMalloc((void**)&db, size);
cudaMalloc((void**)&dc, size);

cudaMemcpy(da, ha, size, cudaMemcpyKind::cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(db, hb, size, cudaMemcpyKind::cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

addArrays << <1, 5 >> > (da, db, dc);

cudaMemcpy(hc, dc, size, cudaMemcpyKind::cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    cout << hc[i] << endl;

//scanf();
getchar();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: прикрепил библиотеки #include <stdio.h> и
#include <cstdlib> и в конце добавил  getch(); и
system("pause"); но программа все равно не останавливается(

Comment: создал проект заного, скопировал предыдущий код и теперь студия на "#include <stdio.h>" выдает ошибку "не удается открыть источник файл "stdio.h""

Answer (score 1):

Вы просто забыли включить стандартный заголовочный файл в котором объявлена функция `getchar()`. Добавьте в начале файла `#include <stdio.h>` и проблема решится.

Comment: Спасибо, странно, что до этого при добавлении библиотеки среда ругалась на    '#include <stdio.h>' но сейчас даже с    'getchar()' на конце, консоль не останавливается и после выполнения сразу закрывается